# Why am I stuck in an endless loop?

Tags: python, loops

I am currently writing a python script and I am running into an endless loop. A similar code is working but this isn't:

```
while True:
    print ("test")
    sleep(2)
    try:
        doc = html.fromstring(page.content)

        XPATH_PRICE = '//div[@id="product_detail_price"]//content()'
        print(XPATH_PRICE)
        RAW_PRICE = doc.xpath('//div[@id="product_detail_price"]')[0].values()[4]
        print("RAW PRICE:")
        print(RAW_PRICE)
        PRICE = ' '.join(''.join(RAW_PRICE).split()).strip() if RAW_PRICE else None
        print(PRICE)

        data = {
            'PRICE': PRICE,
            'URL': url,
        }

        return data
    except Exception as e:
        print e
```

Comment: If you hit the Exception repeatedly it'll never break.

Comment: please tell me what to change

Comment: You have a `while True` loop—that means unlimited looping. Your code returns if the end of the `try` is reached. That will end the loop. Your loop is only infinite if your code keeps raising an exception. Under those circumstances, what behaviour do you want? If you don't want it to loop, why have a `while` at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Change this part**:

```
except Exception as e:
    print e
```

**to this**:

```
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    break
```

And if you are `break`ing while *catching the exception*, there seems to be no point in having a `while True`, remove this part:

```
while True:
    print ("test")
    sleep(2)
```

But if you go with the `while True` approach, put a `break state` somewhere in the loop:

```
while True:
print ("test")
sleep(2)
try:
    doc = html.fromstring(page.content)
    if some_cond:
       break
```

**EDIT**:

Let me try making it simpler. There are two ways from where we are:

**First Approach**:

```
def some_function():
  try:
       #Your expected code here
       return True
  except:
       # will come to this clause when an exception occurs.
       return False
```

**Second Approach**:

```
while True:
    if some_cond
        break
    else:
        continue
```

Considering your Code, I would suggest to opt for the first approach.

**OR**:

If the intention is to still keep `try`-ing unless a specific cond and not `break` on exception:

```
bFlag = False
while bFlag == False:
    try:
        if some_cond:
           bFlag = True
    except:
        continue
```

Comment: If you `break` while catching the exception, then there's absolutely no point in the outer `while True` in the first place.

Comment: Now i get Statement expected, found Py:EXCEPT_KEYWORD at the except Exception part (after deleting while true)

Comment: @Dr.Marc Look for the edit and try grasping the point that you might just not even need the `while` loop.